# How to send IOS Push Notifications with Emoji in message in a NodeJS server?

Tags: node.js, unicode, utf-8

I write some server code to send push notifications. I have a form field, called message. What I need is, putting some Emoji characters in the message.

If I write \ue48d , for a cloud character, server see it as a string '\ue48d'.

How can I decode it so I can use it in a push notification?

Update: Here is my server code. I want to write \exxx to the form's message field, and encode it in this code then send to Apple.

```
exports.create = function(req, res){
    var devices = req.body.devices;
    var message = req.body.message;
    var note = new apn.Notification();
    note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; // Expires 1 hour from now.
    note.badge = 3;
    note.sound = "ping.aiff";
    note.alert =  message;
    note.payload = {'messageFrom': 'Burak'}; 
    for (var i in devices) {
      device =  new apn.Device(devices[i]);
      apnConnection.pushNotification(note, device);
    }

    res.send(200,'Successfull')
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you're using to decode the JSON encoded data on the server.

Comment: I updated. I don't know how to encode/decode unicode strings.

Comment: So what currently do you see on the phone when a push message is sent through that contains an emoji character?

Comment: I write "\e415 Hello!"  to the message field. And in the phone, I see the same "\e415 Hello!" . Unicode character is not converted.

Comment: But you said the server sees '\ue48d' - what happens when you send that to the phone?

Comment: Server see it as a string like "\e415" . When t sends it to the phone, phone sees it also as string "\e415" not the Emoji.

Comment: Sorry \ue48d. I wrote it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep saying different things. You first said:

> If I write **\ue48d** , for a cloud character, server see it as a string
>   **'\ue48d'.**

Now you're saying

> I write **"\e415 Hello!"** to the message field.

At the risk of pointing out the obvious `\ue48d` != `\e415`

UTF8 characters in JSON are encoded like with \u and then the character code i.e. `\ue48d` is a valid character to send to the phone in JSON. `\e415` is not, which is why your phone is not displaying it as an emoji character.

So, what does your phone see when you send `'\ue48d'` to it? i.e. what does it see when you send it the original correctly encoded string.

**Edit**

If it works when you send a properly encoded string from the server, then you probably just need to decode the message sent to the server, before sending it back out i.e.

message = JSON.parse(message);

If the message your server is receiving is just a string, then that should just work as is. If the message is an array or an object, then you will need to pick out the appropriate entry to send to the phone as the message.

Comment: Sorry, it should be \ue48d. And If I send what comes from form field, I see \ue48d in the phone. If I send \ue48d from server, I see Emoji on the phone.